# How do you "notify" a flutter listview.builder when the data aspect in an inheritedmodel is changed

Tags: flutter, dart

In my InheritedModel I have an `idList` which is a List of Strings.

In the CardsPage I have

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> idList =
        ModelData.of(context, aspect: ModelAspects.idList).idList;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: _docCardBuilder,
      itemCount: idList.length,
    );
   }

  Widget _docCardBuilder(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
    String docId = ModelData.of(context, aspect: ModelAspects.idList)
        .idList[itemIndex];

    Map cardData = repo.getById(docId);

    return DocCard(
      key: Key(cardData['id']),
      publishedDate: cardData['date'],
      description: cardData['description'],
      onTap: () => widget.showDetail(cardData['id']),
    );
  }
```

```dart
And elsewhere:
  Future<bool> fetchData(ValueChanged<List<String>> onIdListChange}) async {
    bool savedValue = isBusy;
    try {
      isBusy = true; // Show Modal Spinner;
      setState(() {});

      await repo.refresh();
      onIdListChange(repo.dataCache.idList);  // Callback to the InheritedModel
      return true;
    } finally {
      isBusy = savedValue;  // Maybe clear the spinner
      setState(() {});
    }
    return false;
  }
```

My feeling is that the `listview.builder` itself isn't notified of the change because it shows the original list of cards until theapp is terminated and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want continuous notification when model changes you should be using [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) and if it is one time fetching of data then go for [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

`ListviewBuilder` won't be notified when there is a change in data model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you hope to achieve, but your use of setState() seems a bit funny.

Does your spinner even work like this?

You should use it like this:

```dart
setState(() {
 isBusy = true; // Show Modal Spinner;
});
```

Then the engine will determine which build functions depend on isBusy, and rebuild just these widgets.

In terms of your list of Strings that are not updated, I would suggest to look at the Provider pattern, using a "ChangeNotifier".

This will do what you hope.

See this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier

Comment: It's not the spinner that's not working.  The ListView isn't updating after the repo fetched new updates.

Comment: I know, it was just to show how I would use setState(). But I would normally do what I can to not use it.

I think if you read below, the Provider pattern is what you need. ChangeNotifier. It's quite straight forward.

Comment: actually, I think your problems come from this wrong use of setState. Atleast its dangerous.

setState is intended to "only render the differences inside the setState block. For instance you update the spinner state as I showed you.

By having a blank setState, you are rendinger the entire widget again.

Comment: I will investigate this.  I used to put the changed items in the variable.  Then I started doing things like `if (mounted) setState(....)` based on examples all over Stack Exchange, so basically I'd want the state to update regardless of whether the widget is mounted or not but the setState to run only if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to "subscribe" the ListView Builder to changes to the list.

Two things were needed:
1. In stead of using an external controller to provide the raw data for the listview, use a cache stored in the state of the parent that provide the listview "builder" function (and make the listview use it)
2. Update this cache in the state's `didChangeDependencies` method.

In essence:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardDataModel {
  final String id;
  final String caption;

  CardDataModel(this.id, this.caption);
}

class SomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomePageState createState() => _SomePageState();
}


class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {

  List<CardDataModel> cardData;  // setState after changing this to trigger rebuild

  Widget _cardBuilder(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
    final String cardId = cardData[itemIndex].id;
    return DocCard(
      key: Key(cardId), // Help Flutter know which widget it what
      data: cardData[itemIndex]
    );
  }


  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {  // Magic happens here
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    cardData = TheInheritedModel.of(context, aspect: CARD_DATA_ASPECT).data;
    setState(() {}); // AFAIK this will only be called when the widget is mounted
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: _cardBuilder,
      itemCount: cardData.length,  // Depends expressly on the state property
    );
  }
}

class DocCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final CardDataModel data;

  const DocCard({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text(data.caption),);
  }
}
```